# Dropdownlist can't change selected some times

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, drop-down-menu

I have a big problem I hope some one can help me with it. I'll try to describe it the best I can. please ask if there is something that you did not understand.

I have a dropdownlist that I use for selecting projects with postback enabled, it could look like this

All
Miscellaneous
CodeWithCare
TheAsp.netProject

when the page loads it starts on All(lists all projects)

in the ddlDepartments_SelectedIndexChanged event
the first time I select another value it changes fine. but next time it just keep the selected value and won't change to another item like all.

So the bottom line is. I load the page is says all in the dropdownbox I change the value to
Miscellaneous and then it just keeps the value. I can't change it

my code is here

Code http://pastebin.com/m79f13f0d
HTML markup http://pastebin.com/m50f7af11

Thanks in advance
Entvex

Comment: Do you mean that the selected item in the dropdownlist doesn't change when you change the selection ?
or you mean that the value you take of the selected item is not correct ? please explain more and edit your question again to be clear and avoid language mistakes to make your question understandable

Comment: now i have made it more understandable :) hopes it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        if (Request.QueryString["sup"] != null)
        {
            ddlDepartments.SelectedValue = Request.QueryString["sup"].ToString();
        }
```

this works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting autopostback="true" in the DDL?